# updating my ms access database using ucanaccess connection

Tags: java

I have this codes to update my ms access database using ucanaccess. My codes works find if i update the first row on my database but the problem is that if i update the second row up to the last row this error appears.

"net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:integrity constraint violation:unique constrain or index violation; SYS_PK_10339 table:EMPLOYEETABLE2"

I suspect i made a mistake in my ms access set-up, my primary key is Employee Name and its Data Type is Text.

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
   {                    

                        String employeeName = endrollNameFields.getText();
                        String employeeAddress = endrollAddressFields.getText(); 
                        String employeeStatus = endrollEmployeestatusFields.getText();
                        String employeeDateOfMembership = dateOfMembershipFields.getText();
                        String employeeAge = ageFields.getText();
                        String employeMStatus = maritalstatusFields.getText();
                        String employeeBloodType = bloodTypeFields.getText();                               
                        String employeeGender = genderFields.getText();
                        String beginningCapital = beginningCapitalFields.getText();
                        String grossSalary = grossSalaryFields.getText();
                        String salaryDeductions = salaryDeductionFields.getText(); 
                        String netSalary = netSalaryFields.getText();

                        try
                        {
                            //------------CREATE CONNECTION TO DATA BASE--------------/

                            String DBPAD = "sourceFolder/employeeTable2.mdb";
                            String DB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + DBPAD;                           

                            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB);                  
                            st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                            String sql = "Select * FROM employeeTable2";

                            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);  

                            if (rs != null) 
                                while (rs.next()) 
                                {
                                    rs.updateString("Employee Name", employeeName);
                                    rs.updateString("Employee Age", employeeAge);   
                                    rs.updateString("Employee Address", employeeAddress);
                                    rs.updateString("Employee Marital Status", employeMStatus);
                                    rs.updateString("Employee Date of Membership", employeeDateOfMembership);
                                    rs.updateString("Employee Blood Type", employeeBloodType);
                                    rs.updateString("Employee Status", employeeStatus);                                 
                                    rs.updateString("Employee Gender", employeeGender);
                                    rs.updateString("Beginning Capital", beginningCapital);
                                    rs.updateString("Gross Salary", grossSalary);
                                    rs.updateString("Salary Deductions", salaryDeductions);
                                    rs.updateString("Net Salary", netSalary);                           

                                     rs.updateRow();
                                 }                                  

                            st.close();     


                            st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                            String sql1 = "select * from employeeTable2";
                            rs = st.executeQuery(sql1);

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>" + "<font color=\"#008000\">" + "<html><span style='font-size:1.5em'>Update to Data Base is Successful");

                            endrollNameFields.setText(" "); 
                            endrollAddressFields.setText(" ");
                            endrollEmployeestatusFields.setText(" ");
                            dateOfMembershipFields.setText(" "); 
                            ageFields.setText(" "); 
                            maritalstatusFields.setText(" ");
                            genderFields.setText(" ");                            
                            bloodTypeFields.setText(" ");
                            beginningCapitalFields.setText(" ");
                            grossSalaryFields.setText(" ");
                            salaryDeductionFields.setText(" ");
                            netSalaryFields.setText(" ");                           

                        }
                        catch(Exception e1)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
                        }               
                    }       

                });
```

Comment: You're trying to modify the primary key column, ` Employee Name`, which is resulting in a duplication.  This is caused by the fact that you are selecting all the rows from `employeeTable2` and trying to update them all to the same value

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first row" or "last row" in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify the primary key column, `Employee Name`, which is resulting in a duplication.  This is caused by the fact that you are selecting all the rows from `employeeTable2` and trying to update them all to the same value

To insert a new value, you use a `INSERT` statement, something like...

```
String employeeName = endrollNameFields.getText();
String employeeAddress = endrollAddressFields.getText();
String employeeStatus = endrollEmployeestatusFields.getText();
String employeeDateOfMembership = dateOfMembershipFields.getText();
String employeeAge = ageFields.getText();
String employeMStatus = maritalstatusFields.getText();
String employeeBloodType = bloodTypeFields.getText();
String employeeGender = genderFields.getText();
String beginningCapital = beginningCapitalFields.getText();
String grossSalary = grossSalaryFields.getText();
String salaryDeductions = salaryDeductionFields.getText();
String netSalary = netSalaryFields.getText();

String DBPAD = "sourceFolder/employeeTable2.mdb";
String DB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + DBPAD;

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB)) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into employeeTable2 ("
                    + "'Employee Name', "
                    + "'Employee Age', "
                    + "'Employee Address', "
                    + "'Employee Marital Status', "
                    + "'Employee Date of Membership', "
                    + "'Employee Blood Type'"
                    + "'Employee Status',"
                    + "'Employee Gender',"
                    + "'Beginning Capital',"
                    + "'Gross Salary',"
                    + "'Salary Deductions',"
                    + "'Net Salary') values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

        stmt.setString(1, employeeName);
        stmt.setString(2, employeeAge);
        stmt.setString(3, employeeAddress);
        stmt.setString(4, employeMStatus);
        stmt.setString(5, employeeDateOfMembership);
        stmt.setString(6, employeeBloodType);
        stmt.setString(7, employeeStatus);
        stmt.setString(8, employeeGender);
        stmt.setString(9, beginningCapital);
        stmt.setString(10, grossSalary);
        stmt.setString(11, salaryDeductions);
        stmt.setString(12, netSalary);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>" + "<font color=\"#008000\">" + "<html><span style='font-size:1.5em'>Update to Data Base is Successful");

        endrollNameFields.setText(" ");
        endrollAddressFields.setText(" ");
        endrollEmployeestatusFields.setText(" ");
        dateOfMembershipFields.setText(" ");
        ageFields.setText(" ");
        maritalstatusFields.setText(" ");
        genderFields.setText(" ");
        bloodTypeFields.setText(" ");
        beginningCapitalFields.setText(" ");
        grossSalaryFields.setText(" ");
        salaryDeductionFields.setText(" ");
        netSalaryFields.setText(" ");

    }

} catch (Exception e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
}
```

Now, if you want to update an existing row, you can simply use a `UPDATE` statement, or using your current coding style, select the row which matches the name of the employee and update that row, BUT, this assumes that the name didn't change...

```
String employeeName = endrollNameFields.getText();
String employeeAddress = endrollAddressFields.getText();
String employeeStatus = endrollEmployeestatusFields.getText();
String employeeDateOfMembership = dateOfMembershipFields.getText();
String employeeAge = ageFields.getText();
String employeMStatus = maritalstatusFields.getText();
String employeeBloodType = bloodTypeFields.getText();
String employeeGender = genderFields.getText();
String beginningCapital = beginningCapitalFields.getText();
String grossSalary = grossSalaryFields.getText();
String salaryDeductions = salaryDeductionFields.getText();
String netSalary = netSalaryFields.getText();

String DBPAD = "sourceFolder/employeeTable2.mdb";
String DB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + DBPAD;

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB)) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("Select * FROM employeeTable2 where 'Employee Nam' == ?",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)) {

        stmt.setString(1, employeeName);

        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {

            if (rs.next()) {

                rs.updateString("Employee Name", employeeName);
                rs.updateString("Employee Age", employeeAge);
                rs.updateString("Employee Address", employeeAddress);
                rs.updateString("Employee Marital Status", employeMStatus);
                rs.updateString("Employee Date of Membership", employeeDateOfMembership);
                rs.updateString("Employee Blood Type", employeeBloodType);
                rs.updateString("Employee Status", employeeStatus);
                rs.updateString("Employee Gender", employeeGender);
                rs.updateString("Beginning Capital", beginningCapital);
                rs.updateString("Gross Salary", grossSalary);
                rs.updateString("Salary Deductions", salaryDeductions);
                rs.updateString("Net Salary", netSalary);
                rs.updateRow();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>" + "<font color=\"#008000\">" + "<html><span style='font-size:1.5em'>Update to Data Base is Successful");

                endrollNameFields.setText(" ");
                endrollAddressFields.setText(" ");
                endrollEmployeestatusFields.setText(" ");
                dateOfMembershipFields.setText(" ");
                ageFields.setText(" ");
                maritalstatusFields.setText(" ");
                genderFields.setText(" ");
                bloodTypeFields.setText(" ");
                beginningCapitalFields.setText(" ");
                grossSalaryFields.setText(" ");
                salaryDeductionFields.setText(" ");
                netSalaryFields.setText(" ");

            } else {
                // No matching row, maybe do a insert insetad
            }

        }

    }

} catch (SQLException e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
}
```

Another approach might be to maintain a reference to the original `ResultSet` which was used to load the data and simply update the "current" row with the new data, but you would need to be careful to make sure that the cursor position didn't change to a new row.  Otherwise, you should keep a copy of the original key (`Employee Name`) for the row and use that to select the data from the database when you want to perform an update...

Personally, I think an `UPDATE` statement would be simpler...

You should also be taking more care with your resources, if an exception occurs in your code, it's unlikely to close the outstanding, open resources.

Take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for some more details

(ps It's been a VERY long time since I did any work against a MS Access database, so I might have got the column quoting wrong)

Comment: one more thing my JRE Library is JRE1.8.0_40 I thing the codes above is compatible with JRE Libraries 1.7.

Comment: @MiguelJames I just don't think the OP knows how to manage their resources properly ;)